# Request times out when accessing Active Storage image on http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

On my 5.2.1 rail server running on Apache, if I request an image stored with active storage on http, the request will timeout.
If I use https, the request works. The rest also works, only links given by active storage fail to load.

I need to be able to keep using http, for compatibility reasons.

I tried a rewrite rule to redirect to https, but weirdly it doesn't help, the request still times out.

here is the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(rails/active_storage)$ https://myserver.com/$REQUEST_URI [R=301,L,NC]
```

Active storage link:

Model:

```
has_many_attached :images   
def thumbnail()
            if (self.images.length > 0)
                return self.images[0].variant(resize: "200x200").processed
            end
        end
```

jbuilder:

```
json.thumbnail url_for(post.thumbnail())
```

Comment: Could you include the rewrite rule you tried, along with a snippet of how you generate the active storage URL?

Comment: @David here you go.